# Error resolving template "MeuTemplate", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers SPRING

Tags: java, spring, spring-jpa

Realizando uma requisiçao ajax

```
function buscarDisciplina(){
        var codigoDisciplina = String($("#codigo").val());
        $.ajax({
            url: urlApplication+"/grade-curricular/buscar-disciplina/"+codigoDisciplina,
            type: 'GET',
            data: codigoDisciplina,
            dataType: 'JSON',
            success: function(response) {
                $("#disciplina").val(response);
            }
        });
}
```

O qual chama o controller

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('PERM_GRADE_CURRICULAR_CADASTRAR')")
@RequestMapping(value = "/buscar-disciplina/{codigoDisciplina}")
public Disciplina bucarDisciplina(@PathVariable String codigoDisciplina) {
    return disciplinaService.findByCodigo(codigoDisciplina);
}
```

Service

```
public Disciplina findByCodigo(String codigo){
    return disciplinaRepository.findByCodigo(codigo);
}
```

Repository

```
public Disciplina findByCodigo(String codigo); //uso JpaRepository<Disciplina, Long>
```

Entity

```
@Size(max = 10)
@NotEmpty
@Column(name = "codigo")
private String codigo;
```

Porém ao enviar a requisição 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ele da o erro da imagem acima ...
Estou sem ideia do que pode ser ....

Comment: `urlApplication` que você concatenou na url, está correto?

Comment: Sim , ele vai em cima do controller @RequestMapping(value = "/buscar-disciplina/{codigoDisciplina}") , corretamente , porém da esse erro

Comment: @ProctonTesla experimenta colocar a anotação `@ResponseBody` no seu método `bucarDisciplina`, dessa forma ele mandar um json como resposta, não vai procurar por um template que não existe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro ocorre por que você não colocou a anotação `@ResponseBody` no seu método `bucarDisciplina`, se não colocar essa anotação o Thymeleaf vai tentar encontrar um template com o retorno do método.

Como você quer que somente seja retornado um `json`, basta colocar essa anotação indicando que o retorno do método é o conteúdo a ser exibido pelo navegador

Outra forma de fazer isso é configurar a anotação `@RequestMapping` da seguinte forma:

`@RequestMapping(value = "/buscar-disciplina/{codigoDisciplina}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)`